# Space at end of URL still resolves, but url-specific blocks do not appear. Why?

Tags: blocks, uri

A newsletter went out with a link in a banner containing an errant space at the end:

```
<a href=“http://www.mysite.com/my-landing-page “>
```

Depending on the browser, the URL was either encoded with the “%20” at the end or the space was left unencoded. Either way, the URL was resolved: The page was found and the landing page displayed. However, the sidebar blocks, which were set to only display at certain URLs, did not.

I tested on some other websites, and it’s apparently a Drupal thing; I can create 404s on other non-Drupal sites by adding a “%20” at the end of a good URL.

Why was Drupal able to still display the page, but not the blocks?

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Demo: [Good Link](http://brunellodev.info/drupal/my-landing-page); [Link with a space at the end](http://brunellodev.info/drupal/my-landing-page%20). The block in the left sidebar in the demo is set to only display on the `my-landing-page` path.

Comment: Drupal tends to just accept random extra data at the end of the URL, something I believe is treated as a bug in D8 because Symfony would (correctly) fail to route such a request. It's possible that the blocks system is more picky about it's URL treatment however, as technically we're talking about a different URL. It's interesting though that @AdamBalsam's testing indicates otherwise.

Comment: Yes, that is weird. For me to get the blocks to display on the page with the space, I had to go back in and add the asterisk at the end of the path settings.

Comment: @Mike can you recreate that behavior?

Comment: @Adam sorry which behavior are you talking about?

Comment: @Mike I mean can you recreate the issue with blocks not showing up when a space is added to a URL. I created a clean test environment and was not able to recreate it. Unless you can provide steps for someone to recreate this problem, the only thing we can do is make guesses towards debugging your system, which will likely be futile.

Comment: Note that your example HTML uses wrong quotation marks (`“` instead of `"`).